# Parsing - leftmost and rightmost derivation

Tags: c#, parsing

[image]

process after Left most derivation i think,  im not totally convinced. 
I am just intrigued of how to create a parser in C#. I've been studying the theory for the past couple of days and I have come into something I don't fully understand which is rightmost and leftmost derivations for example:

```
Input  - aa+a*
```

and the grammar is `S -> S S + | S S * | a`

My Solution: 
S
|
S+S
|
S*S+S
|
a+S*S
|
AA+S*A
|
AA + A* 
obviously my paper solution had interior leaves and what not.

I have a solution for this just not convinced its right in the parser tree. 
Any solutions would be very much appreciated. anybody know the right solution including the parse tree?

Comment: You should post a representation of the parse tree from your solution.

Comment: If you can, I recommend you using Antlr (http://www.antlr.org), it is available through NuGet for C#.

Comment: i know about Antlr, but i just would like to understand the parsing techniques and apply them myself for my project

Comment: You should rewrite the text from the image as proper text. It is not that hard.

Answer (score 0):

**Parse Tree**

```
|  |==| a
|  |   
|==|==| a  
|  |
|  | +  
|   
|==| a
|   
| *
```

**How do I build this tree?**

```
given a -> shift (a)
given a -> shift (a)
given + -> reduce ((a) (a) +)
given a -> shift (a)
given * -> reduce (((a) (a) +) (a) *)
```

Comment: I dont suppose you could explain a wee bit please?

Comment: @user3461632 - Show me your solution first.

Comment: S | S + S | S * S + S | A + S * S | AA + S * A | AA + A*             as a tree its hard to write it in this editor unless i stick it in a txt.doc

Comment: @user3461632 - Can you put it in your question and wrap it in a `pre` element?

Comment: done and done, im new to stack so dont know how to display it as a tree.

Answer (score 0):

This parse tree

```
- S
-
  - S
  -
    - S
    - a
  -
    - S
    - a
  - +
-
  - S
  - a
- '*'
```

is produced by [this Perl script](https://gist.github.com/rns/3e11d82428fa6f3c7696#file-parsetree-pl) using a [general BNF parser](http://savage.net.au/Marpa.html). Hope this will help you test various grammar/input combinations you may have.

Comment: interesting. i may need to get into using a parser generator to experiment with.